# Make a zener diode out of a MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, zener

Does anyone know if its possible to wire up a MOSFET transistor as a zener diode? I have been happily making normal diodes from my MOSFETs by shorting the gate and the source

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD8oHk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But now I need a zener diode for a voltage regulator an am struggling to come up with anything! Any ideas would be great...

Comment: What's the advantage on using a mosfet AS a zener, instead of using a zener?

Comment: Chances are you aren't "making a diode" by shorting the gate and source, you are disabling the (n-channel) mosfet and using the internal body diode.

Comment: Why the bleep don't you just use a zener?  A diode is going to be much cheaper than an IRF530... unless you get to sweep the floors at International Rectifier.

Comment: Maybe my first comment sounded condemnatory, but it was really out of curiosity. Do you mind explaining why you intend to do this? I just think it would enrich the question, since without some reason, it's complete nonsense.

Comment: As much as anything it was out of curiosity, just 'is it possible' and because also I have transistors on hand and not any zeners. If its not a possibility its no worries, just thought I'd find out if anyone who knows a lot more than me had any ideas!

Comment: OK stupid idea,  How about if you try  and Zener the body diode you are already using?  So just reverse voltage to your above circuit.  (add some series resistor to limit current maybe 100k?)  Mind you, I have no idea what will happen.  Maybe try a FET with a lower maximum Vds.  I hope you'll post pictures of any carnage!

Comment: I agree with @akohlsmith that the diode behavior is probably from the internal body diode, not the FET. If you're looking to experiment, I have created diodes by shorting VGD and by shorting VDS. You could also stack diodes if you want a different voltage drop. Don't let anyone discourage you from trying something new. If you blow up a part, laugh, take a picture, and move on with the lesson learned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSWdjz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As the drain voltage rises from 0V D1 is not conducting until it reaches its zener voltage (simplistic words). Then a gate-source voltage starts to develop as the drain voltage rises further. At some point (maybe 1V - 4V higher than the zener voltage) the drain starts conducting current and therefore keeping the drain voltage about constant.

Comment: This works as the voltage regulator but I'd really like to not use an actually zener diode, but rather approximate it some how using more MOSFET transistors and resistors

Comment: You can use a resistor instead of the zener - it won't be as sharp but it'll be usable - consider that to start to turn a MOSFET on you might need 2 volts to get maybe 1 uA. At 3V this will be more like an amp so the resistor instead of the zener will work - try it or simulate it.

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty good approximation, as you say not as sharp but could suffice in a pinch!

Comment: @Andy aka .You presented what could be called an amplified zener circuit +1 .I found that high power zeners were expensive and hard to find when I was at school.I would use 2N3055 for amplified zener because they were in my 1976 junkbox .Your mosfet is valid .I have done this when power handling was more important than accuracy and sharpness.These days people are more likely to have Powermos on hand than power BJT .I am a little squeamish about using the latest gen fets in linear mode .The neg tempco of Vgs         threshold does not get balanced by the pos temp co of RDs on at low currents

Comment: @Andyaka, ressurecting this old answer. I don't get how this circuit would work. If it works as a voltage regulator, as a "power zener", where should the load go? Connected to drain and source of M1? But that is the same (unregulated) voltage powering this circuit, so the voltage won't be clamped. Furthermore, what is limiting the current in M1? I've simulated this circuit and feedback alone from R1 won't prevent high currents through M1. Apparently I can't post pictures in comments, right? So I'd show you the simulation results.

Comment: @tfm sounds like you are describing a zener diode which was entirely what this answer was aiming to do. Do you know how a zener diode regulator works?

Comment: @Andyaka, brain lapse here. I assumed, for some obscure reason, that the circuit should behave as a complete regulator/power supply. It is just the equivalent of a power zener, as per OP request. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a Zener diode from a commercial MOS transistor. Zener breakdown (effect) relies on quantum tunneling of electrons trough the thin space-charge region formed in heavily dopped pn junctions [1]. In common MOSFETs, the only heavily dopped regions are the source and drain, while the bulk is usually a lightly dopped p region. Thus, making pn common junctions is easy, but heavily dopped junctions are not available.

Such quantum effects show up in short channel MOS transistors (bellow 65nm), but such devices are not commercially available. Nonetheless, you may try to use the base and emitter regions of a npn bipolar transistor as a Zener diode, due that the emitter is usually a heavily dopped region, but you may expect a higher Zener voltage than the common 5.1 V.

[1] *Principles of electronic materials and devices*, Kasap S.O., McGraw Hill, pag. 444.

Answer (score 0):

Mosfets with heatsinks can handle hundreds of watts. 10 watt zener diode cost about 9£ while 100 watt mosfet is about £0.7. Also if you produce many different power supplies and other products, you only need couple different mosfets in large quantities. If you used zener diodes worst case is that you need a different zener for each product.

Answer (score 0):

This is a smart I idea ,using the build in body diode, but keep ONE thing in mind the recovery of that diode is not that fast meaning that in fast  switching application it will cause problems. I tested it with 200 kHz frequency and its working fine but I cant say it will be the same for 210 kHZ.

The type of problems it can cause it sort circuit of power supply or it will be recovering with a spike a voltage happening on an inductive load destroying the switching MOSFET.